# How do I call eth_getBlockByNumber using Web3WsPropvider of ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js, avalanche

I'm trying to call eth_getBlockByNumber using Web3WsProvider of ethers.js with the following code:

```
const Web3WsProvider = require('web3-providers-ws');
.
.
.

const provider = new Web3WsProvider("wss://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/ws", options);
this.client = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider);



const res = await (this.client as ethers.providers.Web3Provider).send(
      "eth_getBlockByNumber", ["0x0", false]
);
```

but I get an error

```
Error: the method eth_getBlockByNumber does not exist/is not available
```

I am able to make this call through postman and get back a result. Why am I not able to do the same with ethers.js

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this example:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://sample-endpoint-name.network.quiknode.pro/token-goes-here/");
  const blockData = await provider.getBlock("0xc5043f");
  console.log(blockData);
})();
```

Taken from [here](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_getBlockByNumber)